firebase store old user email
I use firebase authorization in my flutter project
In Flutter:
final user = SignInUserModel(
        email: email,
        password: password,
        device: _deviceInfo.model,
        fcmToken: _pushNotificationsService.fcmToken!,
      );

      final res = await _userService.signIn(user);
      if (res.isFail) {
        _toastr.error(res.errorMessage);
        return;
      }

      final res2 = await _auth.signUpWithCustomToken(token: res.value!);
      if (res2.isFail) {
        _toastr.error(res2.errorMessage);

        return;
      }

In backend:
async signIn(user: UserInput): Promise<string> {
    const db = admin.firestore();

    try {
      var userRecord = await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(user.email);
      if (!userRecord) {
        throw 'User or password is not valid'
      }
      await db.collection('users').doc(userRecord.uid).update({ lastSignedIn: Date() })
      var customToken = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(userRecord.uid);
      return customToken;
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }

There is a subscription for user change events in the service:
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    subscribe(_auth.userChanges(), (User? u) async {
      if (u == null) {
        _userSubject.add(AppUser.anonym);
        return;
      }
      final user = AppUser.fromFirebaseUser(u);
      _userSubject.add(user);
    });
  }

I encountered a strange error here. The first time I logged in with the email admin.clima@gmail.com. Then, after a few minutes, I logged in again with user.clima@gmail.com and left it until the next day. However, when I opened the app, _auth.userChanges was triggered, and I saw admin.clima@gmail.com again in the block. Now, after a day, Firebase always returns admin.clima@gmail.com to me, even though I logged in with a different user…
I really don't understand why this is happening. Please help me. Why is this occurring?
